# Jquery ajax , getJson Opera works only with full link

Tags: jquery, opera

i am trying 5 hours to make the simplest script on earth to run in opera.

```
$.getJSON('http://parhs.no-ip.org/gallery/media/list/1?jsoncallback=?' ,
                   {test : "data"},
                        function(data) {
                           // var webPath=data.webPath;
                         alert("ok");
                            });
```

This runs great.. but in my code i dont have http://parhs.no-ip.org/ and works at all browsers except opera..WIthout full link it doesnt work.. Any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: So you are saying you have `/gallery/media/list/1?jsoncallback=?` and it does not work?

Comment: i think that it is a security thing , because when i used a proxy in my browser it worked with /gallery/media/list/1?jsoncallback=?

Comment: If you add an IFRAME with that URL in your page, do you see the contents?